# DateTime 1 Day length

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I want to create a report between days and I choose generate report daily. When I give time interval as 24:00:00.000 it gives an error: 
The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.

23:59:59 is cause delays on my report.

What is the legth of the 1 day in datetime format?

here is my procedure in MSSQL Server

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[Procedure1] 

    @Start datetime, 
    @Finish datetime,
    @TimeRange time
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @TimeRanges as TABLE (SessionStart datetime, SessionEnd datetime);

     with TimeRanges as (
  select @Start as StartTime, @Start + @TimeRange as EndTime
  union all
  select StartTime + @TimeRange, EndTime + @TimeRange
    from TimeRanges
    where EndTime < @Finish )
  select StartTime, EndTime, Count( Test.ScenarioID ) as TotalPeaks
    from TimeRanges as TR left outer join
      dbo.Test as Test on TR.StartTime <= Test.SessionStartTime and Test.SessionCloseTime < TR.EndTime
    group by TR.StartTime, TR.EndTime   
END
```

and call this procedure is here

```
private DataSet GetStoredProcedure1(DateTime StartTime, DateTime FinishTime, DateTime TimeRange)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Procedure1", connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = StartTime;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Finish", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = FinishTime;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeRange", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = TimeRange;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
```

When I give time range 00:05:00.00 for 5 minutes 01:00:00.000 for 1 hour my code doesnt have any problem but when I want a daily report 24:00:00.00 doesn' work. How can I fix that?

Comment: Which language? And please do provide some code to make this easier for us.

Comment: Length of datetime is basically DateTimeValue.AddDays(1). If you supply some code I can tell you where to put it too.

Comment: Do @Timerange need to be dynamic? Otherwise you should be able to do DATEADD(day, 1, startdate) instead of Start + TimeRange. However, my SQL is weak so don't take this for granted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [range of the `time` data type is 00:00:00 to 23:59:59.999...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx). Thus, even if you got C# to create the correct DateTime object for you, you cannot do what you want with the data type you have chosen in your stored procedure.

Since SQL Server does not have a TimeSpan data type like .NET (which would be the correct choice), a simple alternative would be to pass `@TimeRange` as an integer used to specify the number of seconds/minutes/hours (depending on the granularity you want to provide). In T-SQL, add the value to `@Start` using the [`DATEADD` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx).